# How can i make the green arrow aim the middle of the red ones

Tags: javascript, html, geometry

I have 3 canvas, each ones are 200x200, the idea is that the green arrow have to aim to the middle of the red ones.

[image]

I have tried to get the anchor of the 2 main canvas, that are the red ones, and use the angle to rotate the green arrow.

```
function angle(cx, cy, ex, ey){
    const dy = ey - cy;
    const dx = ex - cx;
    const rad = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    const deg = rad * 180 / Math.PI;
    return deg;
}
```

```
const anchor1 = document.getElementById('canva1');
            const rekt1 = anchor1.getBoundingClientRect();
            const anchorX1= rekt1.left + rekt1.width / 2;
            const anchorY1= rekt1.top + rekt1.height / 2;
```

```
const anchor2 = document.getElementById('canva2');
            const rekt2 = anchor2.getBoundingClientRect();
            const anchorX2= rekt2.left + rekt2.width / 2;
            const anchorY2= rekt2.top + rekt2.height / 2;
```

```
const angleDeg = angle(anchorX1, anchorY1, anchorX2, anchorY2);
```

Comment: You can put the *math* tag

Comment: Aren't the "anchor" X and Y values just the coordinates of the center points of two of the canvases? I wouln't expect them to provide any rotational information by themselves...

Comment: @traktor you are right, but i still have no idea how to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using [getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle), you can obtain the css transform in `matrix(...)` form. Parsing its components, calculate the angle of rotation to apply.

```js
function setupArrows() {
    const drawArrow = (canvasName, arrowColor)=> {
        const canvas = document.getElementById(canvasName);
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.strokeStyle = arrowColor;
        ctx.lineWidth = 3;
        ctx.moveTo(100, 100);
        ctx.lineTo(0, 0);
        ctx.moveTo(20, 10);
        ctx.lineTo(0, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(10, 20);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    drawArrow("canva1", "red");
    drawArrow("canva2", "red");
    drawArrow("canva3", "green");
}
setupArrows();

function angle(cx, cy, ex, ey){
    const dy = ey - cy;
    const dx = ex - cx;
    const rad = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    const deg = rad * 180 / Math.PI;
    return deg;
}
function direction(anchor) {
    const m = window.getComputedStyle(anchor).transform.split(',');
    return [ parseFloat(m[3]), parseFloat(m[1]) ]; // [cos, sin]
}

const anchor1 = document.getElementById('canva1');
const anchor2 = document.getElementById('canva2');

const dir1 = direction(anchor1);
const dir2 = direction(anchor2);

const angleDeg = angle(0, 0, dir1[0] + dir2[0], dir1[1] + dir2[1]);

const anchor3 = document.getElementById("canva3");
anchor3.style.transform = `rotate(${angleDeg}deg)`;
```

```html
<div style="padding: 50px;">
    <canvas id="canva1" width="200" height="200" style="border: darkred solid 1px; position: absolute; transform: rotate(15deg);">
    </canvas>
    <canvas id="canva2" width="200" height="200" style="border: darkred solid 1px; position: absolute; transform: rotate(85deg);">
    </canvas>
    <canvas id="canva3" width="200" height="200" style="border: darkgreen solid 1px; position: absolute;">
    </canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: I love you, that's crazy!!